# Multiple actionbar (one per fragment) in activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

Is it possible to add an action-bar to a fragment instead of an activity.

What I am trying to create is a master-detail application with left side dedicated to the master fragment and the right side to the detail fragment. I want to add a dedicated actionbar for each of those fragment.

Does actionbarsherlock/appcompat support this feature or I  would need to create a custom actionbar? / Is there a library which allows you place actionbar like thing within a linear-layout?

Answer (score 1):

`ActionBar` is a feature of `Activity`. You can only control it state from `fragment`, but not to create. So you should implement it yourself.

> Is there a library which allows you place actionbar like thing within
>   a linear-layout?

I don't know, but you can use `<include layout="@layout/custom_action_bar">` for `ActionBar` placing.